# Reset uiview to initial state

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, avfoundation

I am implementing a voice recorder. My viewController have a view(recorderView)in which is hidden initially. When show button is tapped view will appear.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.recorderView setHidden:YES];
}
-(IBAction)show:(id)sender
{
    [self.recorderView setHidden:NO];

}
```

RecorderView have a cancel button. When this button tapped recorder view will be hidden.

```
-(IBAction)cancelTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.recorderView setHidden:YES];
}
```

But here i want to reset uiview to initial state.if user again tapped show button i want to show intial recorderView.is there any method for setting uiview to initial state.Can anyone help me on this
Thanks

Comment: It should work? What's not working

Comment: it is a recorder view, so it contains play ,pause and label showing time of recording.if user recorded some voice timer label will be changed. play button becomes enabled. so if i click cancel i should cancel audio session and replace the view to initial state

Comment: You have to set those all the things manually  when you press cancel button., Want to sow your design with code.